# Backbone.View: delegateEvents not re-binding events to subview

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have broken down this issue into the smallest example possible (i.e., it's only to demonstrate the problem, not to necessarily represent a real-world scenario).

Let's say I have a parent view ("MainView" here) that contains a child view ("SubView" here). If, at any point, I need to re-render the parent view (which thereby re-renders the child view), I am losing the event bindings in the child view, despite calling `delegateEvents`.

A jsfiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ya87u/1/

Here is the code in full:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "div",
    initialize : function() {
        this.subView = new SubView();
    },
    render : function() {
        this.$el.html(this.subView.render().$el); // .html() breaks binds
        this.subView.delegateEvents(); // this re-establishes them
        return this;
    }
});

var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : "div",
    events : {
        "click .button1" : "onButtonPress"
    },
    onButtonPress : function() {
        alert("Button pressed");
    },
    render : function() {
        var html = "<button class='button1'>Button1</button>";
        this.$el.html(html);
        return this;
    }
});

var v = new MainView();
$("#area1").html(v.render().$el); // binds work fine

// do some work... then re-render...

$("#area1").html(v.render().$el); // breaks event binds
```

I do not understand why this is happening. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve the bindings you could do three things.

#### Use $.append instead of $.html

Using `$.append` will keep your bindings intact and also take care that you don't lose any sibling content.

#### Just re-render without re-attaching

In your code you re-render your view and also re-attach it's content. This is not necessary. Simply calling `v.render()` will achieve the same visual result but keep your bindings intact.

```
var v = new MainView();
$("#area1").html(v.render().$el); // binds work fine

// do some work... then re-render…

v.render(); // keeps event binds

$("#area1").append(v.render().$el); // works too
```

#### Use $.empty() before calling $.html()

According to the [jQuery documentation for $.html(htmlString)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

> If you are keeping references to these DOM elements and need them to be unchanged, use .empty().html( string ) instead of .html(string) so that the elements are removed from the document before the new string is assigned to the element.

The important part is that $.html expects an html string, not elements and also unbinds any event handlers present on child nodes. The only way I can explain this behavior is that somehow through transformation of the dom tree to a string and vice versa the events get removed. Interestingly enough, using $.empty() as mentioned in the documentation solves the problem.

```
// any $.html reference needs to have an $.empty too
this.$el.empty().html(this.subView.render().$el);

// and then later for your mainView
$("#area1").empty().html(v.render().$el);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am avoiding `append` because it forces the order of the elements to be dictated by javascript. As for the second suggestion, although that would work in this instance, it would not work if `MainView` was itself a child view of another parent. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GL738/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a reference to the jQuery documentation and a working solution for `$.html`. http://jsfiddle.net/GL738/1/

Comment: That's very interesting. I notice that the jQuery docs mention that such steps should only be required for text content corruption in IE, and yet this issue seems to happen on every browser (all the ones that I've tested so far, anyway). I wonder if this issue is: (a) expected behaviour that was simply not documented, or (b) unexpected behaviour that you've discovered a workaround for, using a solution to another issue.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explaining the jquery pitfall of `.html()`, good to know it!